# Laravel 9 nwidart/laravel-modules issue Console\ShowModelCommand not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-modules

after I've tried to update all the dependencies of our laravel installation (which started from 5.8) all the way to laravel 9 I'm recently having issues when doing the composer update with the nwidart/laravel-modules.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ShowModelCommand" not found

  at vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Commands/ModelShowCommand.php:7
      3▕ namespace Nwidart\Modules\Commands;
      4▕ 
      5▕ use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ShowModelCommand;
      6▕ 
  ➜   7▕ class ModelShowCommand extends ShowModelCommand
      8▕ {
      9▕ 
     10▕ 
     11▕     /**

      +2 vendor frames 
  3   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass("Nwidart\Modules\Commands\ModelShowCommand")

      +7 vendor frames 
  11  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

does anyone know how to solve it ?

tried using other versions of the same module but nothing..

Comment: have you tried ```composer dump-autoload ``` ?

Comment: yes, did not work

Comment: Go back to your version where everything still worked. Maybe `nwidart/modules` has an upgrade guide? Does `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ShowModelCommand` still exist in the framework?

Answer (score 4):

The command `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules:9.0` installs the latest version of nwidart/laravel-modules package for Laravel 9.0

Answer (score 2):

I have facing same issue. Look like `ShowModelCommand` only exists with Laravel 10.
https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Console/ShowModelCommand.html
and Modules version 10 install automatically with `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules`

Try w/ `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules "9.*"` and it will work.

```
Laravel laravel-modules
5.4 ^1.0
5.5 ^2.0
5.6 ^3.0
5.7 ^4.0
5.8 ^5.0
6.0 ^6.0
7.0 ^7.0
8.0 ^8.0
9.0 ^9.0
10.0    ^10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and this is for laravel updated to version 10 and  nwidart/laravel-modules doesn't compatible with that so easily you can run `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules:9.0` to solve temporary your problem:)